# strcasecmp not working with database value

Tags: php

am trying to compare two variable which I select there value from database but it does not work please help me fix this below is the code.

```
$result1 = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events");
$data1 = @mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$dvenue1 = $data1['ven_title']; 

$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM events_location");
$data = @mysql_fetch_array($result);
$dvenue = $data['ven_title'];   
if(strcasecmp($dvenue1, $dvenue) == 0){
echo 'yes';
} else {
echo 'no';
}
```

Comment: why are you putting @ everywhere?

Comment: So what are the actual values that you're retrieving from the database?

Comment: is it always returning no?? its look like, thanks after the strcasecemp

Comment: You are fetching **EVERY SINGLE THING** form the database and compare **the very first thing that MySQL decides to fetch first**. Use an identifier to fetch **exclusively 1 row** with the data you need and **nothing else**. After that, if you are still having troubles, try to delete all the whitespace in the values and then compare.

Comment: Side Note: Use mysqli extension mysql extension is deprecated.

Comment: can you work on my code for me to know where the issue is and if you want to know the value the two variable are returning it is "The Hotel"

Answer (score 0):

As Ismael says, you're fetching all rows from both tables and comparing the first ven_title from each. Regardless of the actual question this seems like an odd thing to do, but I'm presuming you have just one row in each table. The fetch_array method returns a single row from the result set only...

If what you're trying to do is to find events with matching locations then consider doing this in the SQL and testing the result set, perhaps...

```
con = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname, $port, $socket)
    or die ('Could not connect to the database server' . mysqli_connect_error());

$res = $con->query("select distinct e.ven_title from events e, events_location l where e.ven_title = l.ven_title");

if($res->num_rows > 0) {
    echo $res->num_rows . " event found with a matching location.\n";
} else {
    echo "no events with matching locations found.\n";
}

$res->free_result;

$con->close();
```

If you really are trying to compare the values returned from two tables using strcasecmp then you need to strip whitespace from the values you get back. Consider using trim($dvenue1) and trim($dvenue) in your if statement. But don't do this if you're looking for links in a database, that's the databases job :)